# Howto maintain 2d objects on canvas? How to map clicks to objects?

Tags: java, data-structures, drawing, 2d

I need to draw some 2D objects on a canvas in java (rectangles, windows like)

The main goal will be to map 2D coordinates to objects, e.g. to recognize which object was clicked.

**Question:** 
What is the usual way to maintain 2D Object's size / position. (which datastructures etc.)
There should be an effective way to say, which object is at coordinates x,y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i was looking for - was a  [Quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)
For less complicated structures an Array would do.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd use a 'divide and conquer' strategy here: your views (rectangles) contain references to the views that are in that view, instead of putting all views in one big array. Then sort them from left to right, and you can apply a recursive binary search to find the view you're clicking.

No idea how to do this in Java, but a very simple class definition in C++ would be :

```
class MyView {
    std::vector<MyView*> subviews;
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

Searching for the view you clicked is then very simple and fast.